# Cross-site request forgery validation failed. The "state" param from the URL and session do not match.in facebook connection using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I have passed state variable in by URL, and try to get that using state but i got the error :

```
Cross-site request forgery validation failed. 
The "state" param from the URL and session do not match.in
```

i have already SET:

`$_SESSION['FBRLH_state']=$this->input->get('state', TRUE);`

what is wrong?

Comment: Have you made a debug output of both values as a start …?

Comment: Yes, both values are same